# yii2 удаление записи

Tags: mysql, yii2

пробую удалить запись, но вылазит такая вот ошибка "*Error
Call to a member function delete() on array*"

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {

        $this->findAddress($id)->delete(); //указывает что ошибка в этой строке
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }


 protected function findAddress($id)
    {
        if (($model = Addrr::find()->where(['=','parent_id',$id])->all()) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }
    }
```

Comment: скорее всего `findAddress` возвращает массив с одним элементом. Можно попробовать `$this->findAddress($id)[0]->delete()`, а лучше всего посмотреть что он там возвращает и обработать ситуации, когда записью с таким `id` вообще нету и т.д.

Comment: @RTK  [0] - это поле в БД?

Comment: @RTK оно удаляет только одну запись, как удалить все записи, которым parent_id равен?

Comment: [0] - это первая запись в массиве из `findAddress($id)`. Удалить все записи. Чтоб удалить все можно в цикле пройтись по результату из `findAddress` или использовать [Addrr::deleteAll()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#deleteAll()-detail)

Comment: @RTK оно все из БД удаляет, а нужно только то что parent_id= id

Comment: на сколько я знаю там можно указывать по какому принципу удалять, в данном случае Addrr::deleteAll('parent_id = :id', [':id' => $id])

P.S. Обращение через "@" у меня не работает чет

Comment: @RTK, теперь правильно работает, неотходя далеко от кассы, еще вопрос, есть одна форма, из нее нужно переместить данные в две таблицы, по нажатию на одну кнопку, как это делается в yii2, совсем нигде не нашел статей

Comment: извини, с этим не смогу помочь, с Yii уже давно не работаю

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{

    $models = $this->findAddress($id);
    foreach($models as $model){
        $model->delete();
    }
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

или

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    Addrr::deleteAll(['parent_id' => $id]);
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```